# AtomicExchange for records in Delphi

Tags: delphi, concurrency

AtomicExchange requires an Integer or NativeInt variable. So how should I set a value of a record in a thread-safe way?

The record in question looks like this in principle (it has more convenience functions and properties as well in reality):

```
  TStatusCode = record
  private
    FValue: Cardinal;
  public
    constructor Create(AValue: Cardinal);
    class operator Equal(Left, Right : TStatusCode): Boolean;
    class operator Implicit(Value: TStatusCode): Cardinal;
    class operator Implicit(Value: Cardinal): TStatusCode;
    class operator NotEqual(Left, Right : TStatusCode): Boolean;
    property Value: Cardinal read FValue;
  end;
```

Comment: You can protect data access with critical section

Comment: If the data type is larger than 8 bytes then you are out of luck. How big is it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It has a single Cardinal field - that's why I was missing the AtomicExchange in the first place, as I am replacing plain Cardinal values with this record that adds a bit more functionality over it.

Comment: I can't answer the question unless that detail is in the question, for instance with an example type declaration for the record.

Comment: Added the record in the question

Comment: Like `AtomicExchange(Pointer(X), Pointer(Y));` where `X` and `Y` is `TStatusCode`?

Comment: OK, answer coming in a moment.

Comment: @Victoria doesn't compile on 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your record is larger than 8 bytes then there is no hardware support for atomic operations. Otherwise, you can use casts to achieve what you desire. For instance, in your case where the record holds a single 32 bit integer you can do like so:

```
function AtomicExchange(var Target: TStatusCode; Value: TStatusCode): TStatusCode; inline; overload;
begin
  Result := TStatusCode(System.AtomicExchange(PInteger(@Target)^, Integer(Value)));
end;
```

Note that the record must be aligned because that requirement applies to the underlying `AtomicExchange`.

Comment: Shouldn't `Integer(Value)` be `PInteger(@Value)^`?

Comment: @remy Either way. At least this way the compiler verifies that the record size matches integer. Then again, your way avoids invoking the conversion operators. So yeah, perhaps you way is better. Same applies to assigning to result of course.

Comment: Actually, in this case, since the record contains a Cardinal value, I need to use PCardinal and Cardinal to avoid possible range check errors, in case that switch is on.